# A question on the rectangular region defined for a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, terminology, vectors

Let $K = (k_1,k_2,k_3,...k_N)$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$, consider the region  $S_K$ consisting of all vectors $L = (l_1,l_2,l_3,...l_N)$ such that, $|l_i| \le |k_i| \forall i \in \{1,2,3,...N\}$. My question is, given $K$, is there a name for the region $S_K$, used in standard literature? If so, any example reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An $N$-dimensional [rectangular cuboid, or orthotope, or hyperrectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle)...

Comment: How can we relate it to the given vector. Can we call an orthotopr of a vector $K$?